# Transaction unconfirmed after a day! Help!

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I made a bitcoin transaction yesterday and it's still unconfirmed. Maybe the default fee of my wallet was too low. Could anyone please help me get this confirmed? It really is urgent. I'd greatly appreciate it!

Here it is:
https://blockchain.info/tx/1e6ba30a70a6ed95a0095bd672f75e101724751e4a0c22769c0a89813473bebf?show_adv=true

Comment: accelerated ....

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new transaction to the address with a higher fee. There is very little you can do to an existing transaction in the pool.